PdfMapper genera fullstackerror por columna con 6 mil caracteres
Se generó un documento tipo XWPFTable(apache POI),con varias columnas, y una de estas columna contiene información que supera 6 mil caracteres. Cuando se invoca la función endVisitTable(https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport/blob/master/thirdparties-extension/fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf/src/main/java/fr/opensagres/poi/xwpf/converter/pdf/internal/PdfMapper.java), sale error stackoverflowError:null at fr.opensagres.xdocreport.itext.extension.ExtendedPdfPTable.getRowHeight(ExtendedPdfPTable.java). Al aumentar el ancho de la columna, no genera error pero la tabla se desborda del documento.
No he logrado comprender lo que genera el error,y agradecería muchísimo quien posea esta información.
Gracias

